# Reboot a computer from a ROS Node

Tags: python, ros

I want to create a ROS service that will, when called using `rosservice`, reboot the computer.

Here is the code of my callback:

```
def reboot_callback(self, cmd):
    """
    Callback to reboot
    """

    res = TriggerResponse()
    res.success = True
    res.message = "Rebooting"
    os.system('reboot')
    return res
```

But, when I run `rosservice call /reboot` (Or whatever name the service is called), I get a `Permission Denied` Error due to the fact that ROS and Python isn't run as `sudo` and it needs admin privileges to be able to reboot the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the correct privileges to reboot a computer from a ROS node, `roscore` and `rosrun` need to be ran from the root user.

Here's how I did it:

- Get into the root user using `sudo su`
- Source the ROS setup files and the catkin_ws files (`source /opt/ros/kinetick/setup.bash && source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`)
- Run `roscore` and `rosrun` (or `roslaunch` if you have a launchfile) and you now can call your service.

Another way to do it is to use tmux.

- Run tmux on the machine you want to reboot
- ssh to the machine and run `tmux attach`
- run whatever you needed to launch to try and reboot the machine with ros and it should work